# js search bar update on keypress lagging - and how to revert?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i make a search bar on my webpage that:

- filters the items (list items/cards) on my page without pressing enter
- with the current search bar value and updates automatically as user types
- then revert the changes back also when the user deletes letters - (ex: display:none -> display:block)
- in plain js
- also the current search lags 1 key behind

this is where i am trying to implement it
http://codepen.io/lycjee/pen/dNjBPE

and this is the corrseponding code for the search bar

```
searchbar.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

//filter with keypress - without enter
//filter function - on "chan" array

  var filterItems = function(query) {
    return chan.filter(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) <= -1;
    });
  };

//searchquery

  var searchQuery = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;

//declare a var for array of items to be filtered

  var filtered = filterItems(searchQuery);
  console.log(searchQuery);
  console.log(filtered);
  console.log(chan);

//if searchbar is blank and there is a keypress after it
//shows all elements according to the original chan array
//else disables elements according to filtered array

  if (searchQuery === "") {
    for (let i = 0; i < chan.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(chan[i]).style.display = "block";
    }
  } 
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(filtered[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  filtered = chan;
}
```

Comment: Just replace 'keyup' instead of 'keypress'.

Comment: thanks! @KalpeshSingh

any ideas on how to make backspace functional too? i mean updating search when a letter is deleted from the former search

Comment: Create a function which filters based on input values from user. Call that function on `keyup`. It should work!

Comment: @KalpeshSingh thats what i did but it didn't work initially,but initializing the search state at the begining of keyup function did work :) thanks a lot :)